# hands-free Android NFC reader

Tags: android, smart-device, nfc

I am looking for an Android device with NFC reader capabilities, which must be rugged (professional outdoor use) and possibly leaving the operator with free hands. My first choice would be a smartwatch or an wrist/arm band, with a tiny display or buttons to allow basic input from the user. I have only found rugged smartphones, which could be fine but they force the user to pull it out from the pocket or wherever it is and slow down work. Can anyone recommend such device?

Comment: Would a smartphone with something like a lifeproof case work? Or does it need to be rugged out of the box?

Comment: What's your budget?

Comment: I have found already a few smartphones with NFC, but any recommendation is appreciated, especially if supported by experience.
I think rugged out of the box would be better. It will be for people working in dirty environment, wearing gloves, under all weather.
Budget I'd say <200$/€.